# How does AppleCare Protection work overseas? (MacBook Pro 13 inch)

Tags: macbook-pro, applecare

If I buy an apple laptop overseas can I get the apple protection back in UK?

If I buy the laptop and Apple protection abroad, if something has gone wrong will it be protected when I am back in UK.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Inc.
The [AppleCare Protection Plan](https://www.apple.com/support/products/mac.html) provides global repair coverage.

So yes, you are fully covered.

Comment: Yes, I bought my Mac from UK and it had a problem with the ssd and I was in Thailand and they fixed it for free.